# Database publishing issue on Azure from Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure

I am encountering the following error while publishing my database on azure.

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server. the server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.(Provider: TCP
>   provider, error : 0-No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it )".

I am using visual studio 2013, i have also included my proxy in the Windows Azure firewall rules for my IP address..still not working ! 
Does anybody here know a workaround ?

Comment: My connection string from SQL Server Management Studio is dbserver.database.windows.net and everything else is as default. If the firewall is the problem, it will tell you that in the error, yours sounds like you have an incorrect server name. Remember it is the server name not the database name that you need to connect to.

Comment: my server name is nhj0icpgya.database.windows.net,1433, i have checked it again from the azure account and there is no problem with the server name :/